# How do I stop the XSLT from putting a line break between my TEXTAREA tags

Tags: asp.net, xslt, textarea

I have in an xsl file a transform that contains `<TEXTAREA></TEXTAREA>` (no spaces) and when it is transformed the results are

```
<TEXTAREA>
</TEXTAREA>
```

I can't find the right properties to stop this from happening.

We are using `XslCompiledTransform` and `XmlTextWriter`

Thank you.

Comment: You probably need to show us a little more context from your stylesheet, and from your ASP.NET. For example, do you have near the top of the stylesheet `<xsl:output indent="yes" />`? How is the output from the stylesheet being handled (show the ASP.NET code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlTextWriter has a Formatting property that by default is set to Formatting.None. Check that this is the case - if this property were set to Formatting.Indent it would account for the unwanted line-feed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `xsl:strip-space` element at the beginning of the styleheet.

```
<xsl:strip-space elements='TEXTAREA'>
```

Comment: I don't think this would solve his problem. Whitespace stripping is done to the source doc and the stylesheet doc (and not to the output doc). In this case the stylesheet doc has no whitespace node (child of `<TEXTAREA></TEXTAREA>`) to strip. And the source doc should not matter, since it is not used inside the `<TEXTAREA>`.

Answer (score 0):

Unwanted whitespace in the output generally comes from one of three places: it's copied from the source document (often by implicitly applying the built-in template rules to whitespace text nodes in the source); or it's generated by using indent="yes", or (rarely, but worth looking for because it's the last place most people think of) it's copied from the stylesheet because someone put xml:space="preserve" in the stylesheet source.